# replace string in all file names with other string on bash/terminal

Tags: regex, bash, macos

```
UserOnMac$ rename 's/sre/dev' *.sh

rename: error: unrecognized arguments: ngn-sre-guava-run-kops-create.sh ngn-sre-guava-run-kops-delete.sh ngn-sre-guava-run-kops-replace.sh ngn-sre-guava-run-kops-update.sh ngn-sre-guava-run-kops-validate.sh
UserOnMac$
```

I am trying to rename all the files that has SRE with DEV and getting above error.

Comment: `rename` is not a standard MacOS command, you must have installed it from a third party.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: oh I see. thanks so how do I close my question?

Comment: Click on "flag" and ask the moderators to move it.

Answer (score 0):

if occur some error please 
run this command in your shell `brew install rename`
and re-do command again

can try  `rename 's/sre/dev/g' *.sh`

The `g` modifier is only needed if the filenames contain multiple `sre`

To perform a test before actually changing filenames, use the -n flag:

```
user/> rename -n 's/sre/dev/g' *.sh
rename([Anyword]sre.sh, [Anyword]dev.sh)
```

Comment: The error message is complaining about the filename arguments. Would an error in the `s///` command really cause that? The `g` modifier is only needed if the filenames contain multiple `sre` that need to be replaced, it doesn't look like that's the case.

Comment: @Barmar i know use `g` and like replace all `sre` to `dev` . Thank you told me

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
user@MacBook ~/test> touch file_SRE.txt
user@MacBook ~/test> ls
file_SRE.txt
user@MacBook ~/test> mv -v file_{SRE,DEV}.txt
file_SRE.txt -> file-DEV.txt
```

you can use `brace expansion` to replace using {OLD,NEW} in any command.